# iPod is not visible to Banshee 1.5.0

Tags: 9.10, banshee, ipod

I have a brand new ipod nano, and if I plug it in to my media center running Ubuntu 9.10, it gets mounted and I can see it in Nautilus.

Banshee, however, does not list it anywhere. Under preferences/extensions, I've checked that the ipod plugin is enabled.

Rhythmbox could see it okay. I found some forums suggesting uninstalling Rythmbox might help, but it hasn't.

Any other suggestions about why Banshee won't see it? 
Is the ipod too new?
Thanks.

Comment: I've just noticed, that even though the ipod appears in Rythmbox, it doesn't list the songs, or let me copy any on to it. Looks like no ipod action for me in Ubuntu!

Comment: I had the exact same problem with my sister's iPod Nano. I was told that the newer versions have extra Apple evilness to make them difficult to work with Linux. She has to use iTunes on an XP install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banshee upstream is currently moving to libgpod, which is the same library that Rhythmbox uses, when this move is complete you should have better ipod support.

The Banshee team publishes stable releases in a [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) here: 
- https://launchpad.net/~banshee-team/+archive/ppa

However I am not sure if they will backport all the necessary bits to this PPA when the move is complete.

Unfortunately the ipod support in libgpod as shipped in 9.10 is not as good as 10.04, this is one of those cases where an upgrade will probably help you out to get support in Rhythmbox, and in the future (10.10 timeframe) Banshee will improve in this regard as well.

Comment: rythmbox uses "libimobiledevice" (http://www.libimobiledevice.org/), whereas banshee (in ubuntu 10.04 and older at least) uses an older plugin which does not work as well. As Jorge says, upgrading to 10.04 will probably help

Comment: Thanks - it does seem to work fine with Rythmbox on 10.04 - which is alright by me - I like staying up to date!